# AngularJS data model architecture approach

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and having a hard time wrapping my head around the conceptual model.

Let's say I want to have an object hierarchy to model a stash repository: Projects contain Repositories contain Tags. Do I create one app, one module and multiple controllers?  (Can a module have multiple controllers?) Separate app per object type? Separate module per object type?

All the various data types will be populated by making REST API queries. Read-only for now. Does that change things?

Also, why are they called controllers? They seem to be models. As far as I can tell the controller is actually the AngularJS plumbing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my rather simple explanation:

A module is just simply a container for all the bits and pieces of your app (services, controllers, directives, filters etc).

Your *application* may contain different modules - some that you wrote and other third party ones, such as ngGrid for example.

You define a module like this:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

A controller is where the business logic of your application resides. The controller may handle the model, but it is *not* the model. 
The AngularJS documentation for [controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) states:

> Use controllers to:
>
> Set up the initial state of the $scope object. Add behavior to the
>   $scope object.

I break up my controllers in to the logical functions that they are supposed to handle. For example, I've written an app to help with combat tracking in a tabletop RPG. I have a controller that handles martial combat and another that handles magick. I also have another controller that helps with the characters. All these controllers are part of my *combat app*.
I only have one service that is responsible for querying a REST API to retrieve stats and results from a database.

The AngularJS documentation has improved a lot recently and I would recommend reading through it to give you a rough idea of how things work together!

In your example, I'd have a separate controller for each of Projects, Repositories and Tags. I'd have a service to query your datatypes. These would be grouped as part of one module/app.

Comment: I've read the docs but haven't had the a-ha moment yet. Your explanation is very sound though. I'll go back and give the docs another try with this in mind. Thanks!!

Comment: Business logic does not belong in the controller.  Controllers are for wiring up your UI events.  Business logic belongs in the model and services on the client as well on your server.  It is a good pattern to contain business logic in your model with which your services can interact, but again this is not the role of the controller.